# Rendering string with erb content on page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I found many posts with this problem, but it's seems like none of them solves my problem. I got this code which i want to render from string:

```
<%= button_to "/admin/#{contr_name}/#{obj.id}", method: :delete, class: 'btn btn-danger btn-resource-destroy', data: {toggle: 'tooltip'}, title: 'Delete' do %>
   <%= icon('trash-o') %> <span class='sr-only'>Delete</span>
<% end %>
```

I have tried this:

```
template += "<div class='col-sm-4'>"
template += "<%= button_to \"/admin/#{contr_name}/#{obj.id}\", method: :delete, class: 'btn btn-danger btn-resource-destroy', data: {toggle: 'tooltip'}, title: 'Delete' do %>
   <%= icon('trash-o') %> <span class='sr-only'>Delete</span>
<% end %>"
template += "</div>"
ERB.new(template).result(binding)
```

but i get syntax errors.

How i can fix this?

Comment: Please provide the stacktrace, as well as a little bit more information than just "I want to render an erb template as a string.."

Comment: Why do you need it to be rendered as a string?

Comment: Because i am building helper for all index pages that I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to use partials instead.

First, define the partial at, for example, `views/shared/_delete_button.html.erb`:

```
<%= button_to "/admin/#{contr_name}/#{obj.id}", method: :delete, class: 'btn btn-danger btn-resource-destroy', data: {toggle: 'tooltip'}, title: 'Delete' do %>
   <%= icon('trash-o') %> <span class='sr-only'>Delete</span>
<% end %>
```

Then, you can render the partial with the wanted parameters:

```
render 'shared/delete_button', contr_name: [contr_name], obj: [obj]
```

Replacing `[contr_name]` and `[obj]` with whatever you want those variables to be assigned to.

Or, even better, allow the partial to extract the controller's name from predefined variables, like this:

```
<%= button_to "/admin/#{controller.controller_name}/#{obj.id}", method: :delete, class: 'btn btn-danger btn-resource-destroy', data: {toggle: 'tooltip'}, title: 'Delete' do %>
   <%= icon('trash-o') %> <span class='sr-only'>Delete</span> 
<% end %>
```

Now you only need to supply the `obj` when rendering it.

```
render 'shared/delete_button', obj: [obj]
```

You could also use named routes, and do `[route_name]_path(obj)` instead of manually constructing the path.